# sqliteman no longer available?

Tags: sqlite

Just upgraded to Kubuntu 20.04. Been putting it off for ages.

It appears my favorite [`sqlite3` front-end](http://sqliteman.yarpen.cz/) won't install anymore? Any way around this? I use it all the time.

Comment: are you installing it from a repository or building from source code?

Comment: Trying to install from a repository (sudo apt-get install sqliteman)

Comment: You should ask here a concrete question, not just how something appears.